# ggplot 'non-finite values' error

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, tidytext

I have an R dataframe (`df`) that looks like this:

```
blogger; word; n; total
joe; dorothy; 17; 718
paul; sheriff; 10; 354
joe; gray; 9; 718
joe; toto; 9; 718
mick; robin; 9; 607
paul; robin; 9; 354
...
```

I want to use `ggplot2` to plot `n` divided by `total` for each `blogger`.

I have this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(n/total, fill = blogger)) +
  geom_histogram(show.legend = FALSE) +
  xlim(NA, 0.0004) +
  facet_wrap(~blogger, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y")
```

But it yields this warning:

```
Warning message:
“Removed 1474 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).”Warning message in rep(no, length.out = length(ans)):
“'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL”
```

Comment: Non finite suggests a division by zero

Comment: It is because the upper end of your range, 0.0004, is less than many (perhaps all) of your values of `n/total`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the [example plot here](http://tidytextmining.com/tfidf.html#term-frequency-in-jane-austens-novels) that you're working from, there are very long tails at higher `n / total`, and thus the use of `xlim()`. Try making your plot without any change to the limits of the x-axis; you might not need to tweak that at all in your case.

```
ggplot(df, aes(n/total, fill = blogger)) +
  geom_histogram(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~blogger, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y")
```